# Easily Update Master Spreadsheet from Various Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master spreadsheet that we use for tracking a certain activity. The spreadsheet contains various lines with item descriptions, and open columns where end users are to fill in dates.

An updated master spreadsheet goes out to various end users to update date values and return it to the coordinator. The coordinator then takes the various feedback sheets, and updates the master accordingly.

Up to now, this has been quite a labor-intensive task as end-users change filtering settings before sending it back, and there are 1000+ lines, so it is hard to see what the end-users updated.

Does someone know of an effective method to do a task like this, using Excel directly or VBA?

Comment: You can use VBA to loop through all the Excel files in a folder, opening each one in turn and updating the master spreadsheet with that file's data.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a server version of the master spreadsheet so that end-users could check out that document,fill in their dates and avoid the redundancy of having someone retype everything. Sharepoint's ideal for this kind of thing.

If you want to keep it to Excel alone, though, perhaps you could save all the modified user-input-provided workbooks to a designated folder. Then write a macro to loop through each of these files in the folder. Supposing that the cells the users fill/inputting data into were previously empty, check to see if they're now not empty and copy those changes to the master file.